# А как вы определите это КОЛИЧЕСТВЕННО?

Tags: база-данных, сеть, веб-программирование

Регулярно появляются вопросы (дополнения, пояснения к ним в комментариях), в которых авторы говорят например так

```
вопрос о высоко посещаемом сайте с огромной текстовой базой
```

или так

```
очень интенсивная работа с веб
```

Очень хотелось бы понять о каком порядке величин идет речь, когда используются подобные определения?
Например:

1. обмен по сети в Mbyte/sec
2. запросы по сети и к базе в Connect/sec
3. размер базы в Gbyte
4. вычисления в Gflops
5. время отклика в долях sec
6. и т.п.

Пока не хотел бы приводить свои количественные оценки, чтобы не "задавать планку".

--

[@ХэшКод](/users/1/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), я читал правила, где подобного рода опросы не приветствуются, но просто для более полезных ответов мне хотелось бы понимать о каких проблемах на самом деле идет речь в большинстве подобных вопросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что гигабайты и гигафлопсы можно отмести - с такими величинами здесь вопросы не задают :-)

Comment: Похоже это **абсолютный** ответ.